# Beginner Inline Assembly Segmentation fault

Tags: c, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, inline-assembly

I am writing Inline assembly for the first time and I don't know why I'm getting a Seg fault when I try to run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int very_fast_function(int i){
    asm volatile("movl %%eax,%%ebx;"
        "sall $6,%%ebx;"
        "addl $1,%%ebx;"
        "cmpl $1024,%%ebx;"
        "jle Return;"
        "addl $1,%%eax;"
        "jmp End;"
        "Return: movl $0,%%eax;"
        "End: ret;": "=eax" (i) : "eax" (i) : "eax", "ebx" );
    return i;
    /*if ( (i*64 +1) > 1024) return ++i;
    else return 0;*/
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    i=40;
    printf("The function value of  i is %d\n", very_fast_function(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Like I said this is my first time so if it's super obvious I apologize.

Comment: And have a look at the setg instruction. If you empty eax at the beginnning, after the cmpl you can do setg %al and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall not use `ret` directly. Reason: there're initialization like push the stack or save the frame pointer when entering each function, also there're corresponding finalization. You just leave the stack not restored if use `ret` directly.

Just remove `ret` and there shall not be segmentation fault.

However I suppose the result is not as expected. The reason is your input/output constrains are not as expected. Please notice `"=eax" (i)` you write does not specify to use `%%eax` as the output of `i`, while it means to apply constraint `e` `a` and `x` on output variable `i`.

For your purpose you could simply use `r` to specify a register. See this edited code which I've just tested:

```
asm volatile("movl %1,%%ebx;"
    "sall $6,%%ebx;"
    "addl $1,%%ebx;"
    "cmpl $1024,%%ebx;"
    "jle Return;"
    "addl $1,%0;"
    "jmp End;"
    "Return: movl $0,%0;"
    "End: ;": "=r" (i) : "r" (i) : "ebx" );
```

Here To use `%%eax` explicitly, use `"=a"` instead of `"=r"`.

For further information, please read this http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your help! Fixed everything!

Comment: @user2926342 It's always such a pleasure to help :D

Answer (score 0):

`ret` should not be used in inline assembly blocks - the function you're in needs some cleanup beyond what a simple `ret` will handle.

Remember, inline assembly is inserted *directly* into the function it's embedded in. It's not a function unto itself.